# Solving a system of equations with summation

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

How to solve these equations with respect to $x$ and $y$: $$\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{ \sum  }}\left(b_i \left(a_i+b_ix+c_i y\right)\right)=0\land \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{ \sum  }}\left(c_i \left(a_i+b_ix+c_i y\right)\right)=0$$

$a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $x$ and $y$ are reals, and there is exactly one solution! (I think that is the same as n>1, and probably some more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a $2\times 2$ system:
$$\left(\sum b_ia_i\right)+\left(\sum b_i^2\right)x+\left(\sum b_ic_i\right)y=0$$
$$\left(\sum c_ia_i\right)+\left(\sum c_ib_i\right)x+\left(\sum c_i^2\right)y=0$$
BTW, if $b_i=c_i$ for all $i$, does **not** have unique solution.